# Delete method in canvas tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a program where I need a button that need to be both act as create and delete button.The button when acting as a delete button need to delete a canvas can delete the canvas correctly but after creating the canvas again.That will not get created in the same place it gets created below the previous canvas position.

```
from tkinter import *
c=None
def delete():
     c.delete("all")
     button.config(text="Create",command=create)

def create():
  global c
  c=Canvas(root,height=100,width=100)
  c.create_rectangle(10,10,40,40,fill="red")
  button.config(text="Delete",command=delete)

root=Tk()
button=Button(root,text="Create",command=create)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The text of your question asks about deleting 'a canvas', but the code shows deleting objects _on_ a canvas. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Change `c.delete("all")` to `c.pack_forget()` (assume you use `pack()` layout manager).

Answer (score 0):

I think I should've created the canvas container outside the function...Because 
    c.delete("all")
 Will not delete the canvas but it deletes the objects inside it ??
 so whenever i'm clicking on "create" button it again creates new canvas below the old canvas whose objects are totally exhausted